# Run Jenkins in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I started a Java 8 environment in Elastic Beanstalk (Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.8). Then I uploaded a Jenkins WAR file using the "Upload and Deploy" option. But then, the application health got severe, and I am unable to access Jenkins from the Beanstalk assigned public URL (tried with other ports like 8080, 9090 etc. too). What am I doing wrong here?